# How can we use datagrid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

How can we use datagrid in wpf? I can not see the datagrid control in framework 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use free wpf toolkit library.

Answer (score 4):

Actually wpf does not have a datagrid control. But in framework 4.0 it has.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your .net framework will help you imo. It is really easier after that to use Datagrid in wpf, it owns !

[Dabbling Around the new wpf datagrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaimer/dabbling-around-the-new-wpf-datagrid-part-1)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

1. [WPF DataGrid Practical Examples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx)
2. [WPF DataGrid Control - .NET 4.0](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Framework 3.5, WPF does not have a DataGrid Control. But you can get WPF Datagrid, DatePicker, Accordion etc in extended WPF Toolkit. The Extended WPF Toolkit is a collection of WPF controls, components and utilities made available outside the normal WPF Toolkit.
you can donwload the controls from

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/

In Framework 4.0 WPF does have DataGrid and Datepicker.